# Would transferring to a better school in the middle of a graduate program irreparably hurt my professional connections and academic reputation?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, networking

I did not get accepted into any good graduate programs.  For various reasons, I feel I could do much better if I reapplied next year.  This question isn't about the *feasibility* of doing so, but of the affect on my professional reputation and network.

It is an investment for the university to give me funding, so it would be a jerk move to transfer simply for the increase in prestige.  But **how much** of a jerk move would it be?  Would it burn my colleagues and advisors so hard that I would scar my reputation for the rest of my career?  Would I simply lose these people as connections, but have no lasting affect other than that?  Or would everyone be understanding that this is a professional choice, that I am looking out for my future?  (If so, could I request recommendations from professors in the program?)

> If I transfer to a better school either at the end of my first or second year as a graduate student, how much will this piss people off?

To be clear, I am talking about transferring from a mid-ranked state school to somewhere good, at least top 20 hopefully top 10.  And since I am sure this matters, the discipline is mathematics.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, so I'll leave it as a comment.  You should keep in mind that among the students who try to transfer to more prestigious departments, only a minority succeed.  It's reasonable to try, but you should not let it interfere with your studies.  For example, students are sometimes reluctant to explore working with an advisor where they are, since they don't expect to stay, but it's unwise to put this off for several years.  To a first approximation, if you don't transfer by the end of your first year, you should plan under the assumption that you won't transfer.

Answer (score 13):

This is fine. Don't feel guilty at all. I say this as a math professor at a mid-ranked state school, who has written rec letters for students who, for various reasons, wanted to transfer out.

Be sure not to speak ill of the place you're leaving, but you owe it to yourself to seek out the best opportunities available. Good luck!

Comment: I completely agree.  It's possible that someone would hold an irrational grudge, but most people will not mind at all (and you shouldn't worry too much about the few who might).

Comment: Even if you leave, you may still be able to keep bridges by continuing to collaborate with your colleagues at your former school.

Answer (score 13):

### No.

It's *your* degree.  As long as you are honest with *everyone* about your intentions and your motivations, and you don't speak ill of your old department in your application, nobody has cause to label you a jerk.  I recommend asking your current advisor for a recommendation letter, so that the program you're applying to knows (1) that you're not trying to sneak out, and (2) that your current department isn't kicking you out.

Moreover, changing departments is no reason to stop collaborating with your old advisor; that collaboration can pay off handsomely later.  Strong recommendation letters from faculty *outside* your PhD institution are *extremely* helpful for the post-PhD job search.

**I did this.  Some of my former students have done this.  We're all fine.**

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are cordial and tread cautiously, no, it won't. (I know this is a late answer, but since people think of doing this fairly often, I figured I might give my two cents. While I am not a professor, I figured it might help to have a current graduate student's perspective.)

I myself have transferred between math graduate programs at different schools. Furthermore, I know three or four others who have transferred between math programs at different schools, two people who have transferred from a math program to a non-math program at a different school, and two people who have left math programs for a non-math program at the same university. (And no, these people weren't all transferring to or from the same university.) I know many others who have changed advisors or left graduate school entirely. And people often transfer for reasons other than the reputation of the schools, myself included. (Such reasons may include moving to be closer to significant others, dissatisfaction with the geographical location of the school, changing research interests, advisors switching schools and bringing their students with them, advisors ceasing to work with students, and interest in a specific advisor at a different school, among others.) As much as it would be ideal for all graduate students to arrive precisely where they belong and know exactly what they will do over the next four years, it's probably an understatement to say that this doesn't always happen. And many professors are sympathetic and understanding.

I would, however, caution you about the following. Keep in mind that if you don't get accepted into any transfer schools, you probably want to still get good funding and work with an advisor that fits you at your current school. You may indeed later find that you want to stay at your current school, even if you've been accepted to other places!  So, informing those who determine your funding that you're thinking of transferring before you actually have been accepted into another school doesn't necessarily seem like a good idea to me.  Depending on the perspective of the department, it can be like telling your romantic partner that you're thinking of breaking up well before you make the actual decision.  (On the other hand, they might appreciate being informed early and may be very kind and understanding. It's tough to judge, since it all depends on the people involved.)

But if you *do* get accepted into a transfer institution and decide to go there, you should make sure to have a conversation with the heads of your current graduate program and department, to notify them that you are leaving, and to politely express why you are making this change. I'd recommend being brief (you don't need to tell them your life story), but clear, and always polite.  It may be a good idea not to hold off the decision until the last minute (i.e. the April 15th deadline) like I did.  Keep in mind that they need to find someone to replace you, and the closer to the deadline, the harder it is for the school to find qualified candidates.

And I agree that you should be sure not to denigrate your current institution in any of your applications, or when you tell people at your current institution why you're leaving. I also agree that when you apply to other institutions, you should very honestly express why you're making this switch (without denigration, of course).

Edit: Also, regarding Anonymous Mathematician's comment under the question: I transferred after my second year and it's worked out fine, but certainly it is best to be actively pursuing a backup plan for research at your current institution if you're attempting to transfer any later than your first year. That is, keep looking for possible advisors and research projects at your current university even after you've submitted your transfer applications.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to suggest that transferring after two years is impossible or a bad idea.  Rather, I just mean that while applying to transfer it's important to stay focused on a plan that will still work even if the transfer application fails.  I.e., don't make plans that depend on succeeding.  (I've seen students avoid finding an advisor or completing requirements because they hope these issues will become irrelevant when they transfer.  That puts them in a worse position if they don't end up transferring.)

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand now.

Comment: I would definitely agree there. I certainly had backup plans in case my transfer didn't work out.

Answer (score -2):

In my field, which is not mathematics, externally funded studentships are quite common. Leaving an externally funded studentship is completely unprofessional and very bad form. If a student withdraws the PI will generally lose the remainder of the funding and potentially be band from applying in the future.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide scope and context to your answer.  (In particular, rather than telling us what your field *is not*, why not just say what it *is*?)  Also geographic information would be helpful.  In the US "externally funded studentship" sounds like NSF or DoD funding.  In this situation there is no "PI".  Also the idea that a researcher would get banned from funding in the future because their student leaves seems quite draconian: students leave all the time, often for very good reasons.  Where does this sad story take place?